# xcode 6 beta EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0) in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a basic iOS app that sends an HTTP "GET" request on a specified URL and printing that information into a textfield.

I receive no errors but I get a **EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)** error in the `operationQueue` thread. I am new to iPhone development and Swift and even after doing research I'm not sure what this means.

My code is below. My view only contains a button that performs the get method on touch down and a textfield.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var textField : UITextField
    @IBOutlet var button : UIButton

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func get(sender: AnyObject) {
        var url : String = "http://localhost:8080/Booknds/v1/Summary/1"
        var request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()
        request.URL = NSURL(string: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

        //send request
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:{ (response:NSURLResponse!, data: NSData! , error: NSError?) -> Void in

            //get data from URL in dictionary form
            let jsonResult : NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary

            // process jsonResult
            if jsonResult != nil {
                self.textField.text = "\(String(jsonResult.description))"

            } else {
                self.textField.text = "data: \(data), response: \(response), error: \(error)"// couldn't load JSON, look at error

            }

            })
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: which line throws the exception?

Comment: Which beta?  There have been 4 so far.  Also, they have all had their problems, so I can imagine that it must be very frustrating not knowing whether something is your fault or a bug in the product (in my experience, even beta 4 is still pretty buggy).  I'd consider leaving Swift until it stabilises.  Learn Objective-C and Xcode 5.1 first, I don't think it will be time wasted.

Comment: I believe the line "let jsonResult . . . " throws the exception but I can't be certain.  I have the most recent Xcode beta and yes although I am most comfortable in Java-like languages perhaps objective-C would be a better route.  I will probably go down that path if this question doesn't yield any useful responses.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?  I'm facing a similar exception and was wondering what you may have come up with.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message running simple code using the latest Beta. On another machine I'm running an earlier version and the same code works fine - it's in fact the same playground file, stored on Dropbox.